# Kendo grid edit popup mvvm binding seems failed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

Grid popup mvvm binding seems fail when I add a new row and to set value of model attribute in edit eventHandler(model.set("port","udp")) but the select input doesn't change value and from debugger console it shows that event.model's value of property keep unchanged.

But after i manually selecting the port,I try to model.set("port","tcp"),it works!

I am confused of the timing of the binding mechanism of the value field of input element and kendo model binding...

Html part as below:

```
<div class="k-block k-shadow">
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr><td><button class="btn-add" id="ButtonNew" type="button" onclick="addSetting()">New</button></td></tr></table>
</div>
<div class="k-block k-shadow">
  <div id="logForwardingGrid"></div>
</div>
```

javascript as below:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data:{"items":[{"seq":8,"ip":"10.0.0.99","port":36,"protocol":"udp","enable":false}]},
  schema: {
    data: "items",
    model: {
      id: "seq",
      fields: {
        seq: { type: "int", editable: false, validation: { required: false} },
        port: { type: "int",editable: true, validation: { required: true} },
        protocol: { type: "string",editable: true, validation: { required: true} },
        enable: { type: "boolean", validation: { required: true} },
      }
    }
  },
});
$("#logForwardingGrid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  columns: [{
    field: "seq",
    hiddenEdit: true,
    hidden: true
  }, {
    field: "ip",
    title: "IP",
  }, {
    field: "port",
    title: "Port",
  }, {
    field: "protocol",
    title: "Protocol",
    editor: protocalEditor
  }],
  editable: {
    mode:"popup",
  },
  edit: function(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew()) {
        //fail !! e.model's value of property("protocol") keep unchanged
       e.model.set("protocol","udp")
       console.log(e.model)
    }  
  }
});
    function protocalEditor(container,options){
  var data = [{ text: "udp", value: "udp" },{ text: "tcp", value: "tcp" }]
  $('<input id="protocol" name="protocol" required  data-bind="value:'+ options.field +'"/>')
        .appendTo(container).kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource:data,
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
  });

}

function addSetting(){
  $("#logForwardingGrid").data("kendoGrid").addRow();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try supplying a `defaultValue` for the field in your model declaration:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data:{"items": [{"seq":8,"ip":"10.0.0.99","port":36,"protocol":"udp","enable":false}]},
  schema: {
    data: "items",
    model: {
      id: "seq",
      fields: {
        seq: { type: "int", editable: false, validation: { required: false} },
        port: { type: "int",editable: true, validation: { required: true} },
        protocol: { type: "string",editable: true, validation: { required: true}, defaultValue: "tcp" },
        enable: { type: "boolean", validation: { required: true} },
      }
    }
  },
});
```

I don't know why, but that seems to fix the problem. See [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ufEJAlom/2) for working example.

Comment: Yes,I also found that solution at the offial forum. But I want to realize the binding mechanism so that I won’t run into the related issues in the future,thank you!

Comment: It seems to be related to the validation. If you remove the `required` validation from the model declaration and the function where the kendoDropDownList is created, it works fine even without a default value.  So it seems that if you mark a string field as `required` you must also provide a `defaultValue`.

Comment: I am so grateful for your help!

Comment: It seems that after I set the attribute of the model,It then trigger the validation step. And due to lack the default value,so it does not pass the validation and not go next to the data binding step

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. The initial validation failure is probably causing the binding to not be setup properly.